# how to Parse Youtube Api v3 Data json with java

Tags: android, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am looking for help
i got the json url from youtube that contains all the data that i need for my app but i cant find out how i can parse it from json,

i am looking to get the title, amountof views,date and the video id
i just picked up json and i just cant seem to figure it how because most of the guides that i found online are outdated

can anyone help me ? and maybe link me to a guide or help me out?
here is the youtube json data link that i use

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCLrI-dOLyDbRnPyUeWadsOg&maxResults=50&order=date&key=AIzaSyDA7TZB9n2PUoTBGXkK8o_I-4icwk5581w

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON to Java objects using Jackson. Here are few tutorials:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you step by step how can we get all data from youtube with Youtube Api v3 on Java. I am using org.json library.

When I copy your json format to this [site](https://jsoneditoronline.org/), we can see all types.

İt's simple. You want to do 4 data title, amount of views and video id, date.

When I check the title, its path like this items[] --> snippet --> title

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response.toString());
String title = res.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
```

If you want to take all title values with JSON,

```
 for(int i=0;i<res.getJSONArray("items").length();i++) {
            String title = res.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
            System.out.println(i+"-"+title);
        }
```

**Video id**

items[] --> id --> videoId

```
  for(int i=0;i<res.getJSONArray("items").length();i++) {
            String videoId = res.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId");
            System.out.println(i+"-"+videoId);
        }
```

**Amount of views**

pageInfo --> totalResults

We don't need a loop.

```
int totalResult = res.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getInt("totalResults");
        System.out.println(totalResult);
```

P.S : sorry for my bad codes and my English. :/

Comment: I think it must be the first element in the array hence .getJSONObject(0)